# Trigger MySQL not working

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, insert

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `trg_add_role_type_to_auth_item` AFTER INSERT ON role_type 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

INSERT INTO `auth_item` (`name`, `type`, `description`, `bizrule`, `data`)
SELECT role_type.name, "2", role_type.name, "NULL", "NULL" FROM role_type WHERE role_type.role_type_id = 
(SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT 
                    FROM information_schema.TABLES 
                    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME='role_type');

END;
```

what is wrong in this trigger query....
my row got inserted in role_type but do not create in sert in auth_item table.. is it proper way ....  I want to insert value from the last row to the auth_item table on insert in role_type table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In trigger you can directly access the fields of main table using new or old objects.

Try this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `trg_add_role_type_to_auth_item` AFTER INSERT ON role_type 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

INSERT INTO `auth_item` (`name`, `type`, `description`, `bizrule`, `data`)
VALUES (new.name, "2", new.name, NULL, NULL);
END;
```

Comment: me to from ahmedabad... :)